# Варианты ответов в конце не отображаются в том же случайном порядке, что и на предыдущих экранах отдельно

Tags: swift, uikit

Пытаюсь сделать приложение-тест с пятью вопросами и четырьмя вариантами ответов на каждый вопрос.

Все пять вопросов следуют один за другим, то есть каждый вопрос с четырьмя вариантами ответов отображается на отдельном экране.
Затем на последнем экране все вопросы и ответы к ним отображаются на одном экране.

Цель состоит в том, чтобы, во-первых, отображать как вопросы, так и ответы в случайном порядке (когда они отображаются отдельно (1 вопрос и 4 ответа к нему)), так и, во-вторых, чтобы на последнем экране (где уже все пять вопросов и 4 варианта ответов к каждому из них) сохранялся тот же случайный порядок.

С вопросами сохраняется тот же случайный порядок, но ответы на финальном экране не сохраняют того же случайного порядка и отображаются в обычной первоначальной последовательности, в которой они хранятся в базе данных `QuestionManager`.

Как сделать так, чтобы варианты ответов отображались на финальном экране в той же последовательности как в отдельных вопросах, а не как в базе данных?

Ниже приведены примеры отдельного экрана, конечного экрана, базы данных и некоторые отдельные части моего кода.

Примеры 3-5 вопросов с вариантами ответов в произвольном порядке, и финальный экран, где все вопросы в том же произвольном порядке, что и в тесте, а ответы как базе данных `QuestionManager`.

[image: Примеры 3-5 вопросов с вариантами ответов в произвольном порядке, и финальный экран, где все вопросы в том же произвольном порядке, что и в тесте, а ответы как базе данных QuestionManager.]

Фрагмент из базы данных `QuestionManager`.

```
class QuestionManager {
  enum LevelType: String {
    case beginners = "Beginners"
    case middle = "Middle"
    case advanced = "Advanced"
  }
  // MARK: - Properties
  
  private (set) var questions: [Question] = []
  private (set) var answers: [Answer] = []
  /*private (set)*/ var currentQuestion: Question?
  private (set) var questionNumber: Int = 0
  public var levelType: LevelType = .beginners
  
  // MARK: - Constants
  
  public let defaultQuestions: [LevelType: [Question]] = [
    .beginners: [],
    .middle: [],
    .advanced: [
      Question(text: "What is 2 / 2?", answers: [
        Answer(text: "1", correct: true),
        Answer(text: "2", correct: false),
        Answer(text: "4", correct: false),
        Answer(text: "7", correct: false)
      ], explanation: "The correct answer will be is as it is a Singular form."),
      Question(text: "What is 10 / 2?", answers: [
        Answer(text: "1", correct: false),
        Answer(text: "4", correct: false),
        Answer(text: "5", correct: true),
        Answer(text: "12", correct: false)
      ], explanation: "The explanation will be given later."),
      Question(text: "What is 27 / 3?", answers: [
        Answer(text: "9", correct: true),
        Answer(text: "10", correct: false),
        Answer(text: "11", correct: false),
        Answer(text: "12", correct: false)
      ], explanation: "The explanation will be given later."),
      Question(text: "What is 32 / 4?", answers: [
        Answer(text: "7", correct: false),
        Answer(text: "8", correct: true),
        Answer(text: "9", correct: false),
        Answer(text: "10", correct: false)
      ], explanation: "The explanation will be given later."),
      Question(text: "What is 100 / 2?", answers: [
        Answer(text: "30", correct: false),
        Answer(text: "40", correct: false),
        Answer(text: "50", correct: true),
        Answer(text: "100", correct: false)
      ], explanation: "The explanation will be given later.")
    ]
  ]
  
  // MARK: - Public methods
  
  public func shuffleQuestions() {
    guard let questions = defaultQuestions[levelType]?.shuffled() else {
      return
    }
    
    questionNumber = 1
    self.questions = questions
  }
  
  public func upQuestionNumber() {
    currentQuestion = self.questions[questionNumber - 1]
    questionNumber += 1
  }
}
```

GameViewController - контроллер вопросов по отдельности.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
  
  // MARK: - Create
  static func create(with questionManager: QuestionManager) -> GameViewController {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "game") as! GameViewController
    vc.questionManager = questionManager
    return vc
  }
  // MARK: - IBOutlets
  @IBOutlet weak var questionCounterLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!
  @IBOutlet private var questionNumberLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet private var questionNameLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
  
  // MARK: - Properties
  private var questionManager: QuestionManager!
  private var score: Int = 0
  
  let userDefaults = UserDefaults()
  
  // MARK: - Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      configureTableView()
      questionManager.shuffleQuestions()
    }
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    showQuestion()
  }
  
  // MARK: - Configure UI
  private func configureTableView() {
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell")
  }
  // MARK: - QuizGame
  private func showQuestion() {
    questionManager.upQuestionNumber()
    let stepProgress = Float(questionManager.questionNumber - 1) / Float(questionManager.questions.count)
    progressView.progress = stepProgress
    
    questionCounterLabel.text = "\(questionManager.questionNumber - 1)/\(questionManager.questions.count)"
    scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
    questionNameLabel.text = questionManager.currentQuestion?.text ?? ""
    questionNumberLabel.text = "Question \(questionManager.questionNumber - 1)"
    
    tableView.reloadData()
  }
  func pushToResultViewController() {
    let vc = ResultViewController.create(with: questionManager)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
  }
  private func updateUI() {
    progressView.progress = Float((questionManager.questionNumber - 1)/questionManager.questions.count)
    scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
    
    if questionManager.questionNumber > questionManager.questions.count {
      let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Awesome",
                                    message: "End of Quiz. Your result is: \(score) out of \(questionManager.questions.count)! Do you want to start over?",
                                    preferredStyle: .alert)

      let explanationAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Answer explanations",
                                            style: .default,
                                            handler: { action in
                                                self.pushToResultViewController() }
                                            )
      alert.addAction(explanationAction)
      present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
      showQuestion()
    }
  }
}
  // MARK: - UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
  extension GameViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      questionManager.currentQuestion?.answers.shuffle()
      return questionManager.currentQuestion?.answers.count ?? 0
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell else {
        return UITableViewCell()
      }
      cell.textLabel?.text = questionManager.currentQuestion?.answers[indexPath.row].text
      return cell
    }
  }
```

ResultViewController - контроллер последнего экрана, всех вопросов и ответов вместе.

```
class ResultViewController: UIViewController {
  
  //   MARK: - Properties
  private var questionManager: QuestionManager!
  private var questions: [Question] = []
  private var answers: [Answer] = []

  // MARK: - Create
  static func create(with questionManager: QuestionManager) -> ResultViewController {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "result") as! ResultViewController
    vc.questionManager = questionManager
    return vc
  }
  
  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
  
  // MARK: - Private methods
  private func configureTableView() {
    
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomFinalCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customFinalCell")
  }
  
  // MARK: - Lifecycle
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .cyan
    navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
    configureTableView()
  }
}
// MARK: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
extension ResultViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
  
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return questionManager.questions.count
  }
  
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customFinalCell", for: indexPath) as? CustomFinalCell else {
      return UITableViewCell()
    }
        
    let question = questionManager.questions[indexPath.row]
    answers = question.answers
        
    cell.configure(with: question, with: answers)
        
    return cell
  }
}
```

CustomFinalCell

```
class CustomFinalCell: UITableViewCell {
  
  private var questionManager: QuestionManager!
    
  @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var option1: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var option2: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var option3: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var option4: UILabel!
  
  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
  }
  
  override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
  }
  
  // MARK: - Public methods
  
  public func configure(with question: Question, with answers: [Answer]) {
    questionLabel.text = question.text
    option1.text = question.answers[0].text
    option2.text = question.answers[1].text
    option3.text = question.answers[2].text
    option4.text = question.answers[3].text
    }
}
```